# Deciding on lazy initialization on collection instance variables

Tags: java, optimization, lazy-loading

The question is nested inside the code. I have 2 code options. Each listed with pros and cons. Wanted to know a preferred approach.

OPTION1:

```
public class Graph {
    private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;

    /**
     * DISADVANTAGE:
     * 1. Slow to create an object.
     * 2. Memory allocated prematurely, lazy initialization could be used to speed up object creation.
     */
    public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(vertexCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
            adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
    }

    /**
     * ADVANTAGE:
     * 1. No synchronization issues, reducing complexity and overhead of sync.
     * 2. No need to null check, since constructor has taken care of lot .  
     */
    public void addEdge(int vertexFrom, int vertexTo) {
        adjList.get(vertexFrom).add(vertexTo);
        adjList.get(vertexTo).add(vertexFrom);
    }

    /**
     * DISADVANTAGE:
     * 
     * Inspite of knowing that none of the List<Integers> are null, an extra check for size == 0, needed to return  Collections.EMPTY_LIST
     * Eg:
     * if (adjList.get(vertex).size == 0) { return  Collections.EMPTY_LIST; }
     * return adjList.get(vertex).size
     */
    public List<Integer> adj(int vertex) {
        return adjList.get(vertex); 

    }
}
```

OPTION 2

```
public class Graph {
    private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;
    private final int vertexCount;
    private int edgeCount;

    /**
     * ADVANTAGE: quick construction
     * 
     */
    public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(vertexCount);
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
    }

    /**
     * DISADVANTAGE:
     * 1. Effort spent on null checks.
     * 
     * 2. Thread safety complications.
     */
    public void addEdge(int vertexFrom, int vertexTo) {
        if ( adjList.get(vertexFrom) == null ) {
            adjList.add(vertexFrom, new ArrayList<Integer>())
        }
        if ( adjList.get(vertexTo) == null ) {
            adjList.add(vertexTo, new ArrayList<Integer>())
        }
        adjList.get(vertexFrom).add(vertexTo);
        adjList.get(vertexTo).add(vertexFrom);
        edgeCount++;
    }

    public List<Integer> adj(int vertex) {
        if (adjList.get(vertex) == 0) return Collections.EMPTY_LIST; 
        return adjList.get(vertex);
    }


    public List<ArrayList<Integer>> getGraph() {
        return adjList;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Go with the simplest approach. Optimize only when it's necessary and you know where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Spend more time coding and less time optimizing. Unless you have something absolutely mission critical, you're wasting time.

Comment: I prefer "Do it only if required approach", you can pick up piece which meets your current demand.